# Calling a method on a map from another method

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointer-to-member

```
// Penguin.h
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class Penguin
{
    typedef void (Penguin::*PenguinMet)();
    std::map<int, PenguinMet> Methods;

    void Move();
    int p;

public:
    Penguin();
    void Walk();    
};

Penguin::Penguin()
{
    p = 0;
    Methods[0] = &Penguin::Move;
}    

void Penguin::Move()
{
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}

void Penguin::Walk()
{
    this->*Methods[p];
    *this.*Methods[p];
}
```

and this main()

```
// Main.cpp
#include "Penguin.h"

int main()
{
    Penguin Tux;
    Tux.Walk();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run it *p* is never printed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually calling the function, you're just looking at the value of the member function pointer as a void expression, which has no effect.  Change `Penguin::Walk` to this:

```
void Penguin::Walk()
{
    (this->*Methods[p])();
    (*this.*Methods[p])();
}
```

That way you're actually calling the method and passing in the proper arguments (zero arguments, in this case).  Note that you need the extra parentheses, since function calls have higher precedence than the `->*` and `.*` operators.

Comment: Thanks, by the way (*this.*Methods[p])(); doesn't work, I get a access violation error. Do you know what could be?

Comment: @levin: `(*this.*Methods[p])()` is semantically identical to `(this->*Methods[p])()`.  The only reason why it would segfault is if `p` doesn't exist yet in the map, so `operator[]` inserts a default value of NULL, and then you dereference that; however in that case, both method calls would segfault.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you never call the function.

```
void Penguin::Walk()
{
    this->*Methods[p];
    *this.*Methods[p];
}
```

That function does nothing.

```
void Penguin::Walk()
{
    (this->*Methods[p])();
    (*this.*Methods[p])();
}
```

That function calls the thing twice.